# Command in makefile preceeded by backslash

Tags: makefile

What is the effect of adding a backslash before a command in a makefile?

For instance the `\rm` command in this example:

```
# LaTeX Makefile
FILE=report

all: $(FILE).pdf

.PHONY: clean
clean:
\rm *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.log

$(FILE).pdf: $(FILE).tex
pdflatex $(FILE)
pdflatex $(FILE)
bibtex $(FILE)
pdflatex $(FILE)
pdflatex $(FILE)
```

Comment: The effect of the backslash might depend on the operating system, but that looks like an error: a TAB should be there, not a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not needed, but it doesn't hurt anything.  Backslashes inside recipes (unless they're at the end of the line) aren't interesting to make, so they're just passed to the shell.  The shell will see that the next character after the backslash (`r`) is not a special character, so it just ignores the backslash.

Generally people use a backslash before a shell command in order to ensure that no shell aliases are used: the backslash inhibits alias lookup:

```
$ alias foo='echo bar'
$ foo
bar
$ \foo
foo: command not found
```

However, this is not needed in makefiles because make invokes all recipes using `/bin/sh` as a non-interactive shell, so those aliases aren't generally available anyway.